iptables udp packet forwarding
On my Linux machine, I have a UDP server listening on IP 192.168.1.5 port 44123 and an application that sends UDP packets to other devices on the same network, in particular to devices with IP 192.168.1.x port 44124
I want to create an iptables rule to forward all UDP packets from the application to the UDP Server but having difficulties doing so.
Example:
I wish that the application sends a UDP packet to 192.168.1.10 port 44124 and that it is forwarded to the UDP Server listening on 192.168.1.5 port 44123.
Can someone help please?
Note: I have set net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

If I follow this correctly, are you wanting to duplicate every packet sent from the application to the server (presumably to log the traffic)? Is the application running on the same host? Maybe more context regarding the programs might help.

No, I don't want to duplicate the packet but rather forward it to the UDP server which in turn will extract the packet payload and log sensor data.  Yes, the application and UDP server are running on the same host. Any application UDP packet sent to another device on the LAN should be redirected to the UDP Server running on the same host that sent the UDP packet.

@TomYan response to your iptables rule is "iptables v1.8.9 (nf_tables): Invalid rule number `nat'".  Can you check it please?

Oops, sorry, I meant iptables -t nat -I OUTPUT -d 192.168.1.10 -p udp --dport 44124 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.5:44123

@TomYan Thank you very much Tom, it worked.  I changed the rule slightly to capture all outgoing traffic on port 44124 as follows:
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 44124 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.5:44123

@TomYan May I ask, is there a way to get the original destination address after the iptables rule is executed?  For example if I do:   echo "This is the message." > /dev/udp/192.168.1.10/44124, is there a way that my UDP Server can see the original destination IP = 192.168.1.10 and not the iptables rule redirect destination ip = 192.168.1.5?

@JerryPylarinos Not really, unless your application stores it inside the UDP datagram or so.
